# Подправьте прогу, плес:))

Tags: python

помогите, пожалуйста, подправить код.

Задание: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Операция сглаживания матрицы дает новую матрицу того же размера, каждый
элемент которой получается как среднее арифметическое имеющихся соседей
соответствующего элемента исходной матрицы.

Построить результат сглаживания заданной вещественной матрицы размером 10x10.

Код рабочий, но считает неверно. Элемент новой матрицы должен состоять из суммы соседних элементов ИСХОДНОЙ матрицы, а у меня как только он присваивает новое значение элементу, он забывает исходное и считает новое для следующей суммы элементов(объяснила сложно, но на картинке понятнее)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from math import *
from random import *
import numpy as np


def MakeMatr(n, a, b):
    Matr = (b-a)*np.random.random(size=(n,n)) + a
    return Matr


def CorrectMatr(Matr):
    (nRow, nCol) = Matr.shape
    for Row in range(nRow+1):
        for Col in range(nCol+1):
            if Row == 0:
                if Col == 0:
                    Matr[Row][Col] = (Matr[Row][Col+1]+Matr[Row+1][Col])/2
            if Row == 0:
                if Col > 0 and Col < (nCol-1):
                    Matr[Row][Col] = (Matr[Row][Col+1]+Matr[Row][Col-1]+Matr[Row+1][Col])/3
            if Row == 0:
                if Col == (nCol-1):
                    Matr[Row][Col] = (Matr[Row][Col-1]+Matr[Row+1][Col])/2
            if Row > 0 and Row < (nRow-1):
                if Col == 0:
                    Matr[Row][Col] = (Matr[Row][Col+1]+Matr[Row-1][Col]+Matr[Row+1][Col])/3
            if Row > 0 and Row < (nRow-1):
                if Col > 0 and Col < (nCol-1):
                    Matr[Row][Col] = (Matr[Row][Col+1]+Matr[Row][Col-1]+Matr[Row+1][Col]+Matr[Row-1][Col])/4
            if Row > 0 and Row < (nRow-1):
                if Col == (nCol-1):
                    Matr[Row][Col] = (Matr[Row][Col-1]+Matr[Row-1][Col]+Matr[Row+1][Col])/3
            if Row == (nRow-1):
                if Col == 0:
                    Matr[Row][Col] = (Matr[Row][Col+1]+Matr[Row-1][Col])/2
            if Row == (nRow-1):
                if Col > 0 and Col < (nCol-1):
                    Matr[Row][Col] = (Matr[Row][Col+1]+Matr[Row][Col-1]+Matr[Row-1][Col])/3
            if Row == (nRow-1):
                if Col == (nCol-1):
                    Matr[Row][Col] = (Matr[Row][Col-1]+Matr[Row-1][Col])/2
    return Matr


def PrintMatr(Matr):
    (nRow, nCol) = Matr.shape
    for Row in range(nRow):
        for Col in range(nCol):
            print("{0: 7.3f}".format(Matr[Row][Col]), end=" ")
        print()
    print()


n = int(input("Введите размер матрицы (NxN): "))
MyMatr=MakeMatr(n, -10, 10)
PrintMatr(MyMatr)
NMatr = CorrectMatr(MyMatr)
PrintMatr(NMatr)
```

Comment: почему два индекса у матрицы?

Comment: @ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204920/roman-при одиcнаковых выводится неверный результат, матрица получается неровная. Количество элементов уменьшается

Comment: @kirakr, а сам элемент Aij разве не должен учитываться при нахождении среднего? Т.е. если взять окружающую матрицу 3x3 - то среднее считается из 8-ми или из 9-ти элементов?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот, вроде все верно написал.

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def foo(A):
    result = [[0 for j in range(len(A[0]))] for i in range(len(A))]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[i])):
            sum = 0.0
            count = 0
            for k in (-1,0,1):
                for l in (-1,0,1):
                    if k + i in range(len(A) - 1) and l + j in range(len(A[j-1]) - 1):
                        if i == k and j == l:
                            continue
                        sum += A[k+i][l+j]
                        count += 1
            result[i][j] = sum/count
    return result

for i in foo(A):
    print i
```

Answer (score -1):

Варианты решения:

- использовать вторую матрицу для результата
- запомнить две строки и использовать их для расчетов, при переходе к обработке новой строки верхняя вытесняется нижней, на место нижней приходит новая